# Error notices using Linkedin Plugin in Cakephp

Tags: php, api, cakephp, plugins, linkedin-api

I am trying to put a Linkedin plugin in cakephp, using this tutorial http://excellencetechnologies.co.in/Telephonia/blog/linked-login-integration-in-cakephp/

Everything works fine until I login in linkedin but after that I get directed to a page with just this two errors:

```
 Notice (8): OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "OAuthToken" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition [APP\Plugin\Linkedin\Vendor\OAuth\OAuth.php, line 316]

 Notice (8): OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1::build_signature() [oauthsignaturemethod-hmac-sha1.build-signature]: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "OAuthToken" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition [APP\Plugin\Linkedin\Vendor\OAuth\OAuth.php, line 126]
```

I can't find what may be causing them anywhere online so I was wondering if anyone here might know what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever in the code the plugin is pulling the access token from session like this:

`$accessToken = $this->Session->read($this->sessionAccess);`

It is pulling the token in the form of __PHP_Incomplete_Class object. To correct this problem you would have to unserialize the $accessToken like this:

`$accessToken = $this->Session->read($this->sessionAccess);`

$accessToken = unserialize (serialize ($accessToken));

I did it at the three spots in the code to correct it.

Hopefully it will work for you as well.